# Bluemix API connect configuration

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

WE have our REST services deployed using bluemix container groups. Can some one tell me how to configure access to these APIs through Bluemix API Connect? I Created product, catalog. Also imported my swagger in catalog. I can see the APIs listed. but not able to access them. Can someone guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've already created a product, I'll assume that you've already added your API(s) to that product. If not, do that now.

Once you've done that, look for the Stage menu (the little "Cloud with an up arrow" icon) in the upper-right-hand corner of the product detail page. From the corresponding menu, select the catalog you want to stage the product to.

After that completes successfully, navigate to the API Connect dashboard and click on the catalog to which you just staged the product. At this point, you should see the product and its status will be listed as "Staged."

Click the overflow menu (three dots) on the right-hand side of the product row and select "Publish" from the resulting menu. You can likely accept any default visibility settings. Once that operation completes, the API will now be accessible via the catalog's gateway URL + API base path. (You can find this in the Catalog settings -> Endpoint panel.)

For more information on publishing APIs, see this documentation: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/apiconnect/apic_006.html#apic_010

Or if you want to use the CLI: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFS6T/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/capim-toolkit-cli-publish-apis.html#concept_nll_3ry_xv__publish_apis

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt. I have already done all these steps. I am able to stage and publish. But something is going wrong with URLs. Could you please let me know, what should be in Host when configuring API? Do we need to assemble any proxy or invoke for the API?

Comment: The host field should be `$(catalog.host)`. And yes, you need to have an invoke policy in the assembly pointing to the backend endpoint you want managed (e.g. `https://myhost.mycompany.com/`). Additionally, you'll need to use the `$(request.path)` and `$(request.search)` properties to the end of the invoke policy target URL if you want those passed along.

Comment: Thanks. I had identified it later. (catalog.host) worked.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

on Bluemix to call your api , you need to "publish" your product to a portal. First of all prepare your Portal:
Go to Dashboard -- > Your Catalog -- > Settings -- > Enable Portal and select Portal-Delegated-User-Registry.

After some time , you will be accessing your portal . Subscribe new user through that portal. Portal GUI is very helpful. You will be able to learn by yourself how to call your API.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already done all these steps. I am able to stage and publish. But something is going wrong with URLs. Could you please let me know, what should be in Host when configuring API? Do we need to assemble any proxy or invoke for the API?